# joomla php load simple content with modal

Tags: php, joomla, modal-dialog

i use joomla and i am trying to load a modal box by clicking an image. The modal box will containt simple content through a simple div. i have this code but it doesn`t working.

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
<div id="logoutbutton" style="margin-right:-10px;">

<a href=”#test” style=”cursor:pointer” title=”Show popup” rel=”{size: {x: 250, y:300}, ajaxOptions: {method: &quot;get&quot;}}” class=”modal”>

<img src="/images/14.png"  style=" padding-left:2px;  0px; margin-top:7px;   />

</a>
<div style=”display:none”>
<div id=”test”>
popup text
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

any suggestion

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `handler` value:

```
<a href=”#test” style=”cursor:pointer” title=”Show popup” rel=”{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 250, y:300}, ajaxOptions: {method: &quot;get&quot;}}” class=”modal”>
```

Good Luck!